What are the changes in the 1995 edition of The City and the Pillar?
This question contains spoilers for the plot of the novel.
Gore Vidal's The City and the Pillar was originally published in 1948. It was revised and reissued in 1965. In an afterword to the revised edition, Vidal explains that he had originally chosen

to tell the story in a flat gray prose reminiscent of one of James T. Farrell's social documents. There was to be nothing fancy in the writing. I wanted the prose plain and hard and, if I may say so, I succeeded.
Vidal, Gore. The City and the Pillar Revised: including an essay, Sex and the Law, and an Afterword. New York: Dutton, 1965. Link added. Accessed at archive.org 25 July 2024. p. 246.

The changes between the 1948 and 1965 editions are easily noticed. Describing them, Vidal wrote:

I had always meant the end of the book to be black, but not as black as it turned out. I have now altered the last chapter considerably. In fact, I have rewritten the entire book (my desire to imitate the style of Farrell was perhaps too successful), though I have not changed the point of view nor the essential relationships.
ibid., p. 249.

As Vidal says, the most dramatic change is the ending, where Jim Willard rapes rather than murders Bob Ford. Aside from this major plot change, the revisions are confined to the level of style or sentence structure. Nevertheless, they are quite obvious. For example, the revised version opens as follows:

The moment was strange. There was no reality in the bar; there was no longer solidity; all things merged, one into the other. Time had stopped.
      He sat alone in a booth, listening to the music which came out of a plastic box, lighted within. Some of the music he remembered from having heard it in other places. But the words he could no longer understand. He could recall only vague associations as he got drunk, listening to music.
ibid., p. 15.

Here, the original has:

The moment was strange. There was no reality in the bar; there was no longer solidity; all things merged, one into the other. The moment was strange.
      He sat alone in the booth, listening to music. Music came out of a red plastic box, lighted within: all kinds of music. Some of it he remembered; some of the songs he had heard in other places. The words he could no longer understand but he knew what the songs meant and he knew their associations. He was getting drunk and he listened to music.
Vidal, Gore. The City and the Pillar. New York: Grosset and Dunlap, 1948. p. 11.

As these passages show, ending apart, the changes are mainly on the order of wordsmithing.
The novel was published in yet another new edition in 1995, in a volume that also included Vidal's short story collection A Thirsty Evil (1956). The dust jacket claims:

This edition incorporates Vidal's 1965 revisions and some further emendations by the author.
Vidal, Gore. The City and the Pillar: Revised, with a New Preface by the Author, and Seven Early Stories. New York: Random House, 1995. Accessed at archive.org 25 July 2024.

However, Vidal's preface to this edition does not specify what these "further emendations" are. A superficial glance through this revision does not immediately show any major changes from the 1965 text. So: what changes did Vidal make to the 1995 edition of The City and the Pillar? And since he does not justify them as he does the 1965 revisions, what might have been the reason for the changes? Also, were any changes made to the text of the stories in A Thirsty Evil?
